# Git pull request etiquette for repo author - broken style, unrelated changes, partial fixes

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I got my first pull request on GitHub. https://github.com/Ark-kun/Piranha/pull/1

The change is very small and easy to understand.
Unfortunately, I'm a bit too perfectionistic. I see 3 problems with this pull request:

1. Broken style (tabs instead of spaces; missing curly braces)
2. The pull request has two not quite related fixes - it fixed a `NullReferenceException` and fixes the libraries path for Mac OS X.
3. While this request fixes the path for Mac OS X, it doesn't fix it for Linux.

What should I do?

1. Ask the PR author to fix the issues.
2. Just port and fix the code myself and close the PR without accepting it.
3. Checkout the PR branch, fix the style and code, merge the fixed branch. (possibly squashing the commits)
4. Something else.

Answer (score 0):

(1) and (3) are both reasonable options (though I wouldn't squash the other author's commit if you chose #3).

I'd avoid (2) as it omits attribution - chances are you want to encourage people to submit improvements to your project, and attribution is important in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

First option in my opinion is better than others, because making repository public and having pull requests are supposed to help you with your project, so it's good to give credit to people who are trying to help. Hiding their contribution by just porting code and rejecting PR won't encourage them to do more. So I'd definitely avoid option 2. 
Secondly, fixing code by yourself will be waste of your time. I know, it's just a few keyboard shortcuts to fix indentation, but if you let people contribute code, which doesn't match your standards (which are very important to have in a public project, and in general too, of course), you're going to have a lot of fixing in the future.

Github has a lot of options to bring programming society together, and it's really easy to post comments to PR or even lines of code. So when you interact with your contributor, you make him a better programmer, and also his next PRs will be better (hopefully :) ), so it's in your interest. Sometimes really interesting discussions are started in those comments, so it might be learning experience for both of you.

Of course, if the fix is really small, you can pick third "action" and make amends yourself, but I'd contact your contributor about the fixes anyway.